# Java - Sending complete HTTP message (including headers, status line aso)

Tags: java, http

For some reasons I need to develope an own HTTP client. I managed working with the HTTP protocol, but I don't know how to send it via java...

For example, I got the following request message I want to send (I couldn't test it, so I am not sure that it is in a correct format):

```
GET http://example.com HTTP/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:UTF-8
someOtherParam=thatIsThis&name=value
```

All I could find was making up a connection using URL.openConnection() - but with that connection, I can't send the whole message, but have to put the header values via the connection.addRequestProperty() method.

Can anyone help me and tell me how to send such a message to a server?

(And yes; I do know libraries like Apache HttpComponents :))

Best greetings,

Martin Bories

Comment: You would have to use bare sockets, or a very low level networking library to be able to control the protocol in depth. I expect that you will become *very* familiar with the [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) in the process.

Comment: Sorry, wrong answer, my apologies.First set up the queryString. Next, Use URL url = new URL (urlPath+"?"+queryStr); then url.openConnection(), gets you a URLConnection from which you get an InputStream to read the response from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your help - Sockets did it :).

For anyone who is running into the same problem: Use sockets - you can simply write and receive messages and implement an own HTTP implementation.